# Pure Genius Or Pure Stupidity: Does An Old Mac G5 Make A Great BBQ?

Tags: g5, recycle

**This question has some humor as well as practical implications for owners of Apple Mac G5s.**

I came across this earlier on today as an alternative recycling option:

[image]

Source [Macgasm](http://www.macgasm.net/2013/05/20/check-out-this-dude-who-turned-a-g5-into-a-bbq-grill/)

Is this really a viable option (if a little extreme) & what other recycling methods exist for an old Apple Mac G5 ?

Comment: This is very cruel.

Comment: @PaulR I think it illustrates the potential dangers as outlined in Wing Tang Wong's answer below.

Comment: Another use I saw when walking through Harlem the other day... a door stop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I would lean against this for several reasons:

- The aluminum used in the Mac Pro cases isn't food grade metal.
- Some of the adhesives in the case were potentially noxious.

I realize it's tongue in cheek, but keep safe, people. :)

Edit:

The frame of the Mac Pro(s) are basically aluminum. So you can take it to your local metal recycler and have it scraped for aluminum in exchange for money.

You can also refer to [Apple's recycling policies](http://apple.com/recycling).

Ebay/Craigslist are other options, as there are system rebuilders who would love to make use of an old Mac Pro case.

Comment: Excellent reasons why it is such a stupid idea.

Comment: Can you make any comment in your answer as to plausible recycling options for the G5 ?

Comment: http://www.apple.com/recycling/