# What can I use a iMac G5 17" 1.9GHz for?

Tags: imac, g5

I'm very new to the Apple world, and I want to buy iMac G5 17", 1.9GHz, 512GB of RAM (upgraded to 1.5GB) and ATI Radeon X600.

What this machine can do in real life? I mean, these numbers mean to me nothing, I want to know what can I do with thin machine? Can it play ~10GB `.mkv` videos?

Comment: Are you sure about the specs for the machine? iMac G5 was discontinued in 2006.

Comment: You will need to add more concrete questions if you want this question to stay open, try to phrase it more along the lines of "Can this computer do X and Y" where X and Y are your potential use cases.  Using a 10Gb video file is not a real example use case, are we talking 10Gb of 1080p at 60FPS, or a DVD rip, or a really really long VGA webcam quality file?

Comment: @Aidan Certainly do not use it for this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92022/pure-genius-or-pure-stupidity-does-an-old-mac-g5-make-a-great-bbq

Answer (score 1):

It can do moderate Photoshop provided you use version CS2 or earlier. Or do a home server job.
But it's too slow for modern internet (I mean Youtube, Gmail, Facebook, any flash etc.) and it will not play any HD h.264 compressed video (even 720p) without lag.

Have a look at [Geekbench Mac benchmark](http://browser.primatelabs.com/mac-benchmarks) to have a broader picture how this one compares to other Macs